# Unable to Connect to SQL Server 2005 through ODBC drivers from Windows 2012 server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, odbc, ssl

We are unable to connect to a specific Database server which has SQL Server 2005 installed on Windows 2003 server from any of the Windows Server 2012. It used to work till last week, the only change we had on the 2012 server is the latest patches installed (KB4493451, KB4493450, & KB4493435). We have tried uninstalling these patches bit still no luck.

We are still able to connect from any Client system to Database server (SQL Server 2005) and also can login to SQL Server Management Studio which shows Client to Server communication is good, but the problem is with the Server (any Windows 2012 Server) to Database Server (SQL Server 2005).

We have SSL2.0, 3.0, & TLS 1.0 enabled on the DB Server and we have the default protocols SSL & TLS on Windows Server 2012 enabled.  We tried changing the values on the 2012 server for TLS, but still no luck.

[image: screenshot of ODBC error]

> Connection failed: SQL State:'01000' SQL Server Error:1 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (SECCreatedCredentails()). Connection failed: SQLState:'08001' SQL Server Error:18 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][[DBNETLIB]SSL Security error